# Phonegap delete picture / prevent saving in photoalbum with base64 encoded picture

Tags: cordova

I am using the  phonegap getPicture function with the BASE64 string option. I am uploading the image to a server and storing it on the serverside.

My main goal is to prevent the picture beeing saved in the photoalbum on the device. But if that is not possible to do I would like to find the picture and delete it after I have posted it to the server side.

When I receive the BASE64 string if I could get hold of the saved path of the image I could delete it. If I could extract the path for the string that could be a solution. Do if anyone know how to get the path of the BASE64 string it would solve my problem.

Has anyone any experience with similar issues?

The problem is only on android platform, IOs does not seem to store the image.

Here is my code:

```
".command.addpicture vclick": function (element, event) {
var destinationType = 0; //Camera.DestinationType.BASE_64DATA;
var pictureSourceType = 1; //Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
    navigator.camera.getPicture(this.pictureSuccess, this.pictureFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType, sourceType: pictureSourceType});
}

pictureSuccess: function (imageData) {
    this.element.find("#imagedata").text(imageData);
    //places the data in a html element for later posting with other data
},
```

Comment: the picture taken is not saved by phonegap... post the code which u r using

Comment: What platform are you talking about?

Comment: Android and IOs will psot my code in the following post

Answer (score 2):

As @ghostCoder said above, by default the Camera API's getPicture() method should not save the photo into the PhotoAlbum/Camera Roll (certainly not on iOS) unless you send an option `saveToPhotoAlbum: true`.

Comment: Looks good in IOs, no pictures is saved. But in android picture is stored in the photoalbum. Tested the saveToPhotoAlbum: false but no luck.

Comment: If I was you I would raise it as an issue. I think having at least the major platforms behave as constantly as possible is something the project should strive for. http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use PhoneGap to grab the URI,  rather than the base64 data so you have the location to delete the photo if it sticks around  (android). Then,  use the method discussed here to grab the base64 data from the  URI: [Getting an image width and height from Phonegap before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126671/getting-an-image-width-and-height-from-phonegap-before-upload)

Comment: How do you delete it when you have the URI?