# Getting an image width and height from Phonegap before upload

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

This should be easy but I can't find the answer. I need to get the width and height of an image, grabbed via a fileURI in Phonegap, before uploading it to our server. Certainly there's got to be some html5 / Phonegap magic that will do this before uploading. Here is some really reduced code to show where I'm at:

```
function got_image(image_uri) {
    // Great, we've got the URI
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(image_uri, function(fileEntry) {
        // Great, now we have a fileEntry object.
        // How do we get the image width and height?
    })
}

// Get the image URI using Phonegap
navigator.camera.getPicture(got_image, fail_function, some_settings)
```

Any idea what the missing piece is? I wish I had [Simon MacDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41679/simon-macdonald)  or [Shazron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219684/shazron) on speed dial, but I do not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a proper solution.

Pass this function an imageURI. URIs are returned from both of PhoneGap's getPicture() methods.

*Like this:* 
**get_image_size_from_URI(imageURI)**

```
function get_image_size_from_URI(imageURI) {
    // This function is called once an imageURI is rerturned from PhoneGap's camera or gallery function
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObject){
            // Create a reader to read the file
            var reader = new FileReader()

            // Create a function to process the file once it's read
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                // Create an image element that we will load the data into
                var image = new Image()
                image.onload = function(evt) {
                    // The image has been loaded and the data is ready
                    var image_width = this.width
                    var image_height = this.height
                    console.log("IMAGE HEIGHT: " + image_height)
                    console.log("IMAGE WIDTH: " + image_width)
                    // We don't need the image element anymore. Get rid of it.
                    image = null
                }
                // Load the read data into the image source. It's base64 data
                image.src = evt.target.result
            }
            // Read from disk the data as base64
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject)
        }, function(){
            console.log("There was an error reading or processing this file.")
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: This answer works, for the most part, but it's not great. On reading the image data, I'm getting intermittent app crashes due to memory issues. I assume that's because it's trying to read the data all at once. I'd love to find a better method if anyone has ideas. The PhoneGap documentation hints at this problem: " Encoding such images using Base64 has caused memory issues on many newer devices. Therefore, using FILEURI as the 'Camera.destinationType' is highly recommended." http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Comment: Isn't this using FileURI?

Answer (score 3):

The following code solves the same problem for me today (tested on iOS):

```
function got_image(image_uri)
{       
    $('<img src="'+image_uri+'"/>').on('load',function(){
        alert(this.naturalWidth +" "+ this.naturalHeight);
    });
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Something to consider with this approach, is that natural height and width get mixed up on ios 9 safari. Currently running into this issue myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use target width and height of getPicture() to limit the maximum dimension.
If you need to send them to server, I think server code would help to get those dimension.

If you really need to get those dimension by js, you can

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  myCanvasContext.drawImage(img,0,0);
};
img.src = "data:YOUR_BASE64_DATA";
```

And you can do it with img

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but we don't want to resize the image.  Even if we did,  there is no way to determine the aspect ratio of the source image to resize it properly.  Your  second suggestion does not provide a method for obtaining base64  data from a  PhoneGap fileEntry object.

Comment: Although it's too late for you as you have found a way already, you can just passing {destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL} to the getPicture method's param to get the base 64 data instead of getting a  image uri.

Comment: That is really great to know, actually. I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately, the moment I mess with base64 data, either with your method or mine, I get intermittent app crashes. Phonegap documentation touches on this but I'm not sure what the proper alternative is. " Encoding such images using Base64 has caused memory issues on many newer devices. Therefore, using FILEURI as the 'Camera.destinationType' is highly recommended."

Comment: @RyanMartin if you want to resize on the device before uploading while maintaining the aspect ratio just set one of the dimensions when capturing -- targetWidth/targetHeight -- to your target magnitude and then set the other to some very large number (Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY will cause the app to crash).  this will cause any image, portrait or landscape, to be downscaled properly with the original's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

1.Phonegap supply a way to specific the size of the image you choose
[Click here to see the options](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions)

2.If you need to know the original size and do not want to specific, you may try the code below:

```
function got_image(image_uri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(image_uri, function(fileEntry) {
       fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
                    var fileName = fileObj.fullPath;
                    var originalLogo = new Image();
                    originalLogo.src =fileName;
                    //get the size by: originalLogo.width,originalLogo.height
                });
    })
}
```

Comment: I am getting some memory issues with my method so I tried out yours. It always returns 0 width and height. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ryan, too late to see your feedback. However, glad to see your solution. It needs a 'onload' indeedly to get the size of new image object after the image is loaded completely.

Answer (score 0):

one way you can do this is by using the MediaFile from the Capture API.

```
var mediaFile = new MediaFile("myfile.jpg", "/path/to/myfile.jpg");
mediaFile.getFormatData(function(data) {
    console.log("width: " data.width);
    console.log("height: " data.height);
});
```

Should be a lot less code than the current accepted solution.

Comment: Hey Simon - thanks for responding. Unfortunately this code doesn't seem to work for me. I'm currently testing in iOS where the code always returns a width and height of zero. Shazron mentioned over the weekend that he thinks it's not possible to safely get the width and height of an image prior to upload without a substantial memory hit. I think I might abort this attempt and wait to hear back from my server with a proper with and height. Not an ideal situation though.

Comment: yeah, that works on Android but it appears not to on iOS. You may be stuck waiting for a response from your server.